# Monaco trigger autocomplete when typing word in custom lang?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

I basically want to use the [Monaco editor](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react) for React to write in a fantasy language, a natural language (just plain text). I will write words in English, and the autocomplete will translate them into the fantasy language (this is an easier way to learn the vocabulary of a fantasy language, perhaps). So basically, I write English words, and as I type it autocompletes with a list of matching English words, and when I tab it should append the fantasy word.

How can I do this?

Here is what I've tried:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
import Editor, { Monaco } from '@monaco-editor/react'
import type monaco from 'monaco-editor'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import draculaTheme from '~/configurations/dracula.monaco.json'

export const configuration = {
  brackets: [
    ['{', '}'],
    ['[', ']'],
    ['(', ')'],
  ],
  comments: {
    lineComment: '#',
  },
}

function createDependencyProposals(
  monaco: Monaco,
  range: monaco.IRange,
): Array<monaco.languages.CompletionItem> {
  return [
    {
      documentation: 'beautiful',
      insertText: 'byut',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
      label: 'beautiful',
      range,
    },
  ]
}

export const languageDef = {
  defaultToken: '',
  tokenizer: {
    root: [{ include: '@whitespace' }, { include: '@strings' }],
    strings: [[/\w+/, 'string']],
    whitespace: [[/\s+/, 'white']],
  },
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
function initializeEditor(monaco: Monaco) {
  monaco.editor.defineTheme(
    'dracula',
    draculaTheme as monaco.editor.IStandaloneThemeData,
  )

  monaco.languages.register({ id: 'bead' })

  monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider(
    'bead',
    languageDef as monaco.languages.IMonarchLanguage,
  )

  monaco.languages.setLanguageConfiguration(
    'bead',
    configuration as monaco.languages.LanguageConfiguration,
  )

  return monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('bead', {
    provideCompletionItems: function (
      model: monaco.editor.ITextModel,
      position: monaco.Position,
    ) {
      // find out if we are completing a property in the 'dependencies' object.
      console.log('here')
      const range = {
        endColumn: position.column,
        endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
        startColumn: 1,
        startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
      }
      var textUntilPosition = model.getValueInRange(range)
      var match = textUntilPosition.match(/beau/)
      if (match) {
        return { suggestions: createDependencyProposals(monaco, range) }
      }
      return { suggestions: [] }
    },
    triggerCharacters: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  })
}

type TextEditorPropsType = {
  defaultLanguage: string
  height: string | number
  lineNumbers?: boolean
  onChange?: (string?: string) => void
  readOnly?: boolean
  value?: string
}

const Container = styled.div(props => ({
  background: props.theme.colors.black,
  marginBottom: 16,
  marginTop: 16,
  paddingBottom: 16,
  paddingLeft: 16,
  paddingTop: 16,
}))

export default function TextEditor({
  height,
  defaultLanguage,
  onChange,
  lineNumbers,
  readOnly,
  value,
}: TextEditorPropsType) {
  const [completionDisposable, setCompletionDisposable] =
    useState<monaco.IDisposable>()

  const handleBeforeMount = (monaco: Monaco) => {
    setCompletionDisposable(initializeEditor(monaco))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    completionDisposable?.dispose()
  }, [completionDisposable])

  return (
    <Container>
      <Editor
        height={height}
        theme="dracula"
        value={value}
        defaultLanguage={defaultLanguage}
        beforeMount={handleBeforeMount}
        onChange={onChange}
        options={{
          acceptSuggestionOnEnter: 'off',
          autoClosingBrackets: 'always',
          contextmenu: false,
          cursorStyle: 'line',
          fontSize: 16,
          hover: {
            // enabled: false,
          },
          minimap: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          parameterHints: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          quickSuggestions: {
            comments: true,
            other: true,
            strings: true,
          },
          readOnly,
          scrollbar: {
            alwaysConsumeMouseWheel: false,
            // handleMouseWheel: false,
          },
          suggestOnTriggerCharacters: true,
          tabCompletion: 'on',
          tabSize: 2,
          wordBasedSuggestions: true,
          wordWrap: 'off',
          ...(lineNumbers
            ? {}
            : {
                folding: false,
                glyphMargin: false,
                lineDecorationsWidth: 0,
                lineNumbers: 'off',
                lineNumbersMinChars: 0,
              }),
        }}
      />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And then I use it as:

```
<TextEditor
  height={400}
  defaultLanguage="bead"
/>
```

I am getting this though:

[image]

I would expect when I type the first letter `b` in `beautiful`, it should find `beautiful` from the list and replace it with `byut`.

Things I tried:

1. **triggerCharacters**: I tried setting `triggerCharacters: ['?']`, though I don't know what trigger character means. Does this mean the character that *accepts* the autocomplete, or that initializes the autocomplete? I would like for it to autocomplete on every lowercase alphabet character `/a-z/`.
2. **Adding `languageDef` and `configuration`**. Not sure if those are necessary, but I added them.
3. **Changing the editor options**. Like `suggestOnTriggerCharacters: true` and the like. But leaving out all custom options, I get the same result (no autocomplete).

I'm missing something fundamental here I think, in wiring this up.

Bead is not a programming language, it is a spoken language written in lowercase letters separated by spaces. So I want to write in lowercase letters an English word, and have it spit out the fantasy word. How can I do that? What am I missing?

It should be logging `here`, but it never does.

Also, I would like to avoid having to press `CTRL+Space` to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following code to configure an autocomplete that converts text typed in English to the fantasy language. As you're using React and TypeScript you might need to convert it slightly.

```
function createDependencyProposals(range) {
    return [
    {
      documentation: 'beautiful',
      insertText: 'byut',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
      label: 'beautiful',
      range: range
    },
    {
      documentation: 'faster',
      insertText: 'fsut',
      kind: monaco.languages.CompletionItemKind.Keyword,
      label: 'faster',
      range: range
    }
  ]
}

// Register the custom language
monaco.languages.register({id: 'bead'});

// Register the completion provider
monaco.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider('bead', {
    provideCompletionItems: function (model, position) {
        // Get the text before the cursor
      var word = model.getWordUntilPosition(position);
      var range = {
        startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
        endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
        startColumn: word.startColumn,
        endColumn: word.endColumn,
      };
      // Compute the suggestions
      return {
        suggestions: createDependencyProposals(range),
      };
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: '',
    language: "bead",
});
```

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2518#issuecomment-861268439), `triggerCharacters` are additional characters other than `a-z` that will also trigger suggestions (e.g. if you want to trigger suggestions when typing `.`, `!` etc), so you won't need to define any explicit trigger characters if you just want to trigger suggestions when typing `a-z.

Here's a working [Monaco Playground demo](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html?source=v0.40.0#XQAAAAKCBAAAAAAAAABBqQkHQ5NjdMjwa-jY7SIQ9S7DNlzs5W-mwj0fe1ZCDRFc9ws9XQE0SJE1jc2VKxhaLFIw9vEWSxW3yscw6v9nt8FMVJpPoRyBdi9M1_G4fz_GHkPnDw5FYv-hVPgAMoHABKlIQkHYWMMCXnGIWgbD2KDANUBt7sO4zW-lX85kQe9TKh35Taf52uM4EvtTtYXZh1mH-ZG7TOShVKcJczJoDr_EaJvAYDEM8jHeekiDmY20jIQaykSBzmSZkXpej-bX_c00SeQM9IxZBukOPPAKgqSQHUT1k2FLggrUl0yfsFHuJVs55ReQIGK8NMANCPfwVy1nwuszAD7XvRleXttuYQvJN53AvLCIcXuj7tu8PnCdtzpzNyAVr1938sgRpLPCWymxfu8xQpamgV_ULvWlRZ1uRQAnTGiZJZYSbpA-W9B3yKHvimC6pYMWOz5LfyH48IJFld_W9b4Ro5hEFWLuqjfbMbZgx2yyprm_3dGrAo2DsN4L9H5fnu-tHcsxHsEAZu-yHTo5lVk1kZM-1kABNRmvdoJcff7DJ-tPMAgsZG5VxtnPyi2a6is1ZsCwj3JklFFWqsFy_Gp6FfYod9eNWKOoexGLDWaklTWJNlzo1ba_NiqmnVa3o7uZc5bb9MULUzlCi7458ka5_STbOlbIY0gA1kOzlLawzjqVgs98_qPMgKAOvVTDB0acv7H-11p4). You should be able to start typing the English word, e.g. type `bea`, the suggestion `beautiful` will appear, and if you select it (press `Enter` or click on it), it will insert the Bead word into the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like monaco won't trigger if your tokenizer is matching `string`, here:

```
export const languageDef = {
  defaultToken: '',
  tokenizer: {
    root: [{ include: '@whitespace' }, { include: '@strings' }],
    strings: [[/\w+/, 'string']],
    whitespace: [[/\s+/, 'white']],
  },
}
```

the `@strings` rule matches `\w+` as soon as you type a char, marking it a string token class thus autocompletion will not trigger, you can fix it by changing `string` to `identifier`